# QwtPicker: disable movement of cursor via arrow keys

Tags: c++, user-interface, plot, qwt

According to the [Qwt documentation](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_picker.html) of QwtPicker (which is a superclas of QwtPlotZoomer, the class I'm using) the cursor can be moved using the arrow keys:

```
The cursor can be moved using the arrow keys
```

However, I wan't to disable this, as the arrow keys have different purposes in my application.

Is this possible via the API? Otherwise I need to subclass my QwtPlotZoomer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just ended up overriding the relevant functions of QwtPicker, this works fine.

```
class MyQwtPlotZoomer : public QwtPlotZoomer
{
    public:
        MyQwtPlotZoomer(int xAxis, int yAxis,  QwtPlotCanvas* canvas, bool doReplot = true) : QwtPlotZoomer(xAxis, yAxis, canvas, doReplot){ }

        virtual ~MyQwtPlotZoomer(){ }

    protected:
        virtual void widgetKeyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* ke)
        {
            if ( !isActive() )
            {
                if ( keyMatch( KeyUndo, ke ) )
                    zoom( -1 );
                else if ( keyMatch( KeyRedo, ke ) )
                    zoom( +1 );
                else if ( keyMatch( KeyHome, ke ) )
                    zoom( 0 );
            }
        }

        virtual void widgetKeyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent*){ }
};
```